# Windows Service starts and runs but no Stop or Shutdown options appear in Management Console

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2013, windows-services, windows-7-x64

I have created a proof-of-concept Windows Service in Visual Studio 2013 service project (in C#) along with the installer components. It installs and runs correctly, writing a record to a database every 5 seconds. I can see that it's working.

It is a Manual start. The `CanShutdown` and `CanStop` properties are set to **True**, and yet these options are grayed out in the Management Console's Services window.

I've uninstalled (installutil /u   fooservice.exe) and rebooted and reinstalled, and have gotten success messages each time.

I've opened **compmgmt.msc** as Administrator, with no difference.

What have I neglected to do?

Comment: What language?  Is this a .NET service?

Comment: Yes, it is a .NET service (C#)

Comment: Does the Services administrative tool say that the service is "running" or "starting"?  (Or something different?)

Comment: It starts and runs. properly.  I think I've found the answer. and will confirm after some further testing. The Account was not specified in the installer.